# Creating and displaying a basic BST in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm sure I'm making some silly mistake, hope somebody can help me out and clear some of my basic concepts.

Here's my code to create and print a basic BST in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct bst
{
    int value;
    struct bst *left;
    struct bst *right;
}T;

T *temp=NULL, *newnode;
T *tree; // had globally declared as NULL previously

T* createnode(int val)
{
    newnode=(T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
    if(newnode==NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->value=val;
        newnode->right=NULL;
        newnode->left=NULL;
    }
    return newnode;
}

T * insert_tree(T *tree, int val)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
    {
        newnode=createnode(val);
        tree=newnode;
        return tree;
    }

    if (val < tree->value)
    {
        tree->left=insert_tree(tree->left,val);
    }
    else if(val > tree->value)
    {
        tree->right=insert_tree(tree->right, val);
    }
    return tree;
}

void display_preorder(T *tree) //changed to accept parameter
{
    if(tree)
    {
        printf("%d \n", tree->value);
        display_preorder(tree->left);
        display_preorder(tree->right);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    insert_tree(tree,34);
    insert_tree(tree,45);
    insert_tree(tree,88);
    insert_tree(tree,87);
    display_preorder();
    return 0;
}
```

It runs and executes without error, but, the output screen is blank.

Can somebody please point out the errors and mistakes?

Thank You.

Comment: `tree` holds NULL when you call `display`. Can you figure out why?

Comment: Hint: Why does `int f(int i) {i = 7; return i;} int main() {int x = 0; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` not print 7?

Comment: `tree=newnode`. That operates on the *local* copy of `tree`, not the global one as you seem to intend. Result is that the global `tree` always remains NULL.

Comment: @immibis because it's NULL globally?

Comment: @immibis I changed global declaration and removed the NULL assignment, still not displaying anything.

Comment: @kaylum my bad, changed that, still not displaying anything

Comment: "changed that". Don't see it. All I see is that you no longer explicitly initialise the global `tree` variable (though no net change as globals are initialised to zero automatically anyway). `insert_tree` is still operating on a local `tree` and not the global `tree`.

Comment: `display_preorder(tree->left)` and that is very bad. `display_preorder` is not properly defined to accept parameters. Are you sure that even compiles?

Comment: @kaylum again , changed print function to accept parameters, I used the same method in creating and displaying a Doubly Linked list, let me check about insert function changing the globally initialized tree.

Comment: @kaylum  as I said, silly mistake, I was not assigning value to tree in main, just needed tree=insert(tree, value) in the main, prints fine now, thank you :) Any suggestions to improve my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the insert_tree function.
Because your function gets only a pointer of a tree and not a pointer to a pointer you returned the value.
So, in the main you should place the tree equal to the function.
Your function gets the tree pointer by value and not by reference.
like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    tree = insert_tree(tree, 34);
    tree = insert_tree(tree, 45);
    tree = insert_tree(tree, 88);
    tree = insert_tree(tree, 87);
    display_preorder(tree);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```